# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "airflow"

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a CentOS 7 instance,and I've installed `airflow` and `postgresql` on top of that.

Initially installed the postgres-server and the contrib via yum by following the steps here:

https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-postgresql-on-centos-7/

upon installation, then I started the postgres service and checked the status whether it's up and running.

After this I installed `apache-airflow` by using the following command:

```
pip3 install "apache-airflow[postgresql]==2.3.1" --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.3.1/constraints-3.7.txt"
```

Then followed the steps [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#setting-up-a-postgresql-database) to create the airflow user, db via the psql cli.

Finally I updated the airflow.cfg with the correct sqlalchemy conn details:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@localhost/airflow
```

Once I start to run `airflow db init` it throws me this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:
> Ident authentication failed for user "airflow"

The pg_hba.conf looks like below:

[image]

I could also see the airflow user and the airflow db via psql

[image]

Not sure where am I going wrong? Any help could be appreciated.

NOTE: Postgresql version - 9.2.24 || Airflow version - 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems very similar to this thread, have you checked it out?

[airflow postgresql backend: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "airflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383798/airflow-postgresql-backend-psycopg2-operationalerror-fatal-ident-authenticat)

In your case, you also have the uncommented line:

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

So I would start by reading that thread, and trying to remove this line :)